# Django prefetch_related

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a relational model set that has 5 tables each with a one to many relationship. I'm having trouble accessing model information after the 2nd table. ex.

```
class TableA(models.Model):
  pass

class TableB(models.Model):
  tablea = models.ForeignKey(TableA, oncascade...)

class TableC(models.Model):
  tableb = models.ForeignKey(TableB, oncas...)

class TableD(models.Model):
  tablec = models.ForeignKey(TableC, ...)

class TableE(models.Model):
  tabled = models.ForeignKey(TableE, ...)
```

In my views.py i'm using the prefetch related method on TableA:

```
from . models import *
data = TableA.objects.all().prefetch_related('tableb_set__tablec_set__tabled_set')
```

I can't seem to access information from TableC, TableD or TableE.

```
for a in data:
  print(a.id)
  for b in a.tableb_set.values():
    print(b['id])
    for c in b.tablec_set.values(): #This is where I get an error message stating the model doesn't have a relatedmanager
```

How can I access model information 2+ tables deep into the prefetch_related relationship?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you define a `related_name` in your `ForeignKey`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Check if your code example does align with your source code and that you don't have any typos in there.

```
for a in TableA.objects.prefetch_related(
    "tableb_set__tablec_set__tabled_set__tablee_set"
):
    print(f"+ {a.id}")
    for b in a.tableb_set.all():
        print(f"+- {b.id}")
        for c in b.tablec_set.all():
            print(f"+-- {c.id}")
            for d in c.tabled_set.all():
                print(f"+--- {d.id}")
                for e in d.tablee_set.all():
                    print(f"+--- {e.id}")

for query in connection.queries:
    print(query["sql"])

# prints:

+ 1                                                                                                                                                                        
+ 2                                                                                                                                                                        
+- 2                                                                                                                                                                       
+-- 2                                                                                                                                                                      
+--- 2                                                                                                                                                                     
+--- 11                                                                                                                                                                    
+---- 3
+-- 4
+- 5
+-- 1
+--- 4
+--- 6

[...]

SELECT "main_tablea"."id" FROM "main_tablea"
SELECT "main_tableb"."id", "main_tableb"."a_id" FROM "main_tableb" WHERE "main_tableb"."a_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
SELECT "main_tablec"."id", "main_tablec"."tableb_id" FROM "main_tablec" WHERE "main_tablec"."tableb_id" IN (2, 5, 6, 4, 1, 3)
SELECT "main_tabled"."id", "main_tabled"."tablec_id" FROM "main_tabled" WHERE "main_tabled"."tablec_id" IN (5, 9, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 8)
SELECT "main_tablee"."id", "main_tablee"."tabled_id" FROM "main_tablee" WHERE "main_tablee"."tabled_id" IN (4, 6, 2, 11, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10, 5, 9)
```

Comment: This is a reverse lookup so the _set is required.

Comment: I was accessing the lower relationships wrong. Thank you jnns!!

Answer (score 0):

using the `.all()` method on the `_set` accesses the info!